# Netsuite Item Search - Goal: show items of non-zero quantities available

Tags: netsuite, items, saved-searches

I'm creating a current inventory value search. It is an item search and the results show the item name, quantity on hand, cost, base price and formula(cost*quantity on hand). I need one more result to appear. Last date sold. I can not seem to find this field anywhere on the open fields. so i am looking for and a work around. to display the last sell date so that we can gauge our inventory better.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to link to the Transaction fields, filter by Type (Invoice, Sales Order or Item Fulfillment) and in the results select a date field with summary type Max.  You would also need to apply Group or a summary type to the other fields for them to display.

Comment: How do I specifically link a transaction, and verify that the transaction is the last sales order?

I also would need a little bit of help selecting the correct type of summary, do you know of any good articles that map out how to set up result summaries?